# Update data field in progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Can someone please help me?

All I want to do is update a field in a table, lets say for example membership number if it meets certain conditions.

For example: I have a list of membership numbers. IF the numbers on the list match the membership number in the table - we don't do anything.

If it doesn't match - then we change the membership number to another number that is stored in my input CSV. (i know this sounds back to front, but this is just an analogy)

So in essence I am asking - how do you update a field in a database table?  This doesn't seem to be working:

```
def stream inputStream.
def stream outStream.

def var abcData           as char extent 4 no-undo.

def var vl-XYZ# as integer.
def var vl-link# as integer.
def var vl-orig-ABC# as char.
def var vl-new-ABC# as char.
/* def var vl-error as char. */
def var vl-match as char.
def var vl-status as char.

def buffer bMembers for  members.

input stream inputStream from "/home/abc.csv".

output stream outStream to "/home/xyz.csv".

export stream outStream delimiter "'" "ABCID" "Match".
 
repeat:   
   
    assign
    abcData = "".
        
    import stream inputStream delimiter "'" abcData.

    assign
    vl-link# = integer(abcdata[1])
    vl-XYZ# = integer(abcData[2])
    vl-orig-ABC# = string(abcData[3])
    vl-new-ABC# = string(abcData[4])   .           

 
   for each account no-lock  where account.link# = vl-link#,
    First members no-lock where  members.XYZ# = vl-XYZ#:

        if members.abc# = vl-orig-ABC# then
            assign
                vl-status = "Needs amending".
        
        if members.abc# <> vl-orig-ABC# then
            assign
                vl-status = "No action needed"
                members.abc# = vl-new-ABC#.
    

 
export stream outStream delimiter "'" vl-link# vl-XYZ# vl-orig-ABC# members.abc# vl-status
```

]

Comment: It would be very helpful to describe "doesn't seem to be working" ... is it just not updating the record or is there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with updating the members records will be in the FOR EACH. You need to use EXCLUSIVE-LOCK with the members table to be able to update records.

```
   for each account no-lock  where account.link# = vl-link#,
    First members EXCLUSIVE-LOCK where  members.XYZ# = vl-XYZ#:
```

The selection criteria for the members table does also not seem to be right, in a joined FOR EACH statement, the second table should depend on the first one like

```
   for each account no-lock  where account.link# = vl-link#,
    First members EXCLUSIVE-LOCK where members.<somefield of members> = account.<matchine ield in account> 
                                   AND members.XYZ# = vl-XYZ#:
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. The exclusive-lock worked. my test spreadsheet ran well - so I am not sure if my attempt to join tables worked. I suspect it doesn't work.  I thought about what you said and that makes sense - looking at those two tables. account and members. they don't seem to have a shared field. Do I need to pull another/3rd table in there that has a shared field between 2 of them? If so, how do I do that? Thank you much appreciated

Comment: That is hard to answer without knowing those tables at all

Comment: the signatory table shares the members# field with the members table and it shares the account# field with the accounts table.  Sorry I know, I am so new to this.. i dont know if this is sufficient